# How to extract out specific information from files within a directory?

Tags: command-line, bash

I have a around 50 files which are named in the format: ERR*.log (i.e. ERR23432.log, ERR12356.log, and so on...). From each file I want to extract a specific information (value). Within each file, there are values at the end of the lines: `final pair1 : Total reads after merging results from multiple database` and `final pair2 : Total reads after merging results from multiple databases`. You can see these lines in the 62nd and 63rd line of the [attached](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DkOe7SE4BX2aGjBhF5dk0wUIhomYB_Rj/view?usp=sharing) file.
Now, I want a script that will extract these values and add them to get a single value for each file. And then, it will give an output file with the extracted informations where the first column will be the name of the file without the extension (i.e. ERR45666 in the attached example) and the second column with the added value. Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: Sorry to say CHANDA7 but your question has attracted dickheads that have already cluttered up the comments. Let us know if you make any progress on your own.

Comment: Not really. I knew how to find a line using grep. But, my target is more complicated like extracting the last word (numerical value) from the lines extracted by grep. Then, add them up. Then, make two columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU awk:

```
gawk '
  BEGIN {print "SampleID","Read_counts"}
  BEGINFILE {sum = 0} 
  /final pair[12] : Total reads after merging results from multiple database/ {sum += $NF}
  ENDFILE {print substr(FILENAME,1,length(FILENAME)-4), sum}
' *.log
```

With standard (POSIX) awk, you can easily fake the `BEGINFILE` using `FNR==1` but the `ENDFILE` pattern is harder; in that case I'd suggest using an array for the sum, keyed on the current filename, and printing everything at the `END`

```
awk '
  BEGIN {print "SampleID","Read_counts"}
  FNR==1 {k = substr(FILENAME,1,length(FILENAME)-4)}
  /final pair[12] : Total reads after merging results from multiple database/ {sum[k] += $NF}
  END {for(k in sum) print k, sum[k]}
' *.log
```

Note that with this approach, the output order is not guaranteed to be in the same order as the glob expansion of the filenames `*.log`.

Comment: Many many thanks  @steeldriver. It is helping me a lot. I have tried to add column names (`SampleID` and `Read_counts`) using `echo -e` but it is not running. Why?

Comment: @CHANDA7 if you want column names, add them in a `BEGIN` rule to the awk command ex. `BEGIN {print "SampleID","Read_counts"}`

Comment: Are you instructing me to edit like this? - `gawk '                                      
BEGIN {print "SampleID","Read_counts"}  /final pair[12] : Total reads after merging results from multiple database/ {sum += $NF}
  ENDFILE {print substr(FILENAME,1,length(FILENAME)-4), sum}
' *.log 
`  I have removed `BEGINFILE {sum = 0}` and added `BEGIN {print "SampleID","Read_counts"}`. Is everything fine?

Comment: @CHANDA7 I never said anything about removing `BEGINFILE` - they serve different purposes. I have edited the answer to show what I mean. In future, please include **all** your requirements in the question rather than adding them in comments - ideally, by including the desired output as well as the sample input.

Comment: Thanks alot @steeldriver. I am sorry for too many questions. I will follow your suggestion in the future posts.